# ios: Where to put the Sqlite file in solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, ipad

I am new to iOS development, I am making changes in  an application which is using Sqlite. I am to add some new fields in some tables, I browsed DB with software and added new fields in 
**inventory_db_src.sqlite** but when I see in emulator it uses **inventory_db.sqlite** which is strange as there is no **inventory_db.sqlite** file in solution and neither code creating DB through SQL script. And If I debug code it gets **inventory_db.sqlite** path successfully and never executes **inventory_db_src.sqlite** line and put inventory_db.sqlite in emulator where my new fields are not present as I put these in **inventory_db_src.sqlite**. pLease help me

```
BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inventory_db.sqlite"];
        //      [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbPath error:nil];
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        success = NO;

        if (success) {
            int savedVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kVERSION_KEY];
            if (kCURRENT_DB_VERSION != savedVersion) {
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbPath error:nil];
                success = NO;
            }
        }
        if (!success) {
            // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inventory_db_src.sqlite"];
            success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }

        _INVENTORY_DB = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:dbPath];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your statement it seems that old DB is cached in to your Emulator. please reset you Emulator by

> iOS Simulator -> Reset content and settings

And it should work ...

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 in your code above is showing the name as inventory_db.sqlite, so that is the file your app will be using. You need to modify that to use the new database name. Be aware, that by modifying your database, you might have unexpected results so you will need to manage what DB version your app is using and make data corrections as needed. This is one nice feature that Core Data can assist in.